# Proper syntax for MySQL 5.0.x FEDERATED table creation?

Tags: mysql, mysql5, mysql-5.0, federated-table

So I'm trying to create a federated table using the syntax from [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html).  Following this, I've created a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `federated_table` (
  `table_uid` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  ...,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table_uid`)
) ENGINE=FEDERATED DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 CONNECTION='mysql://user:password@host.name:3306/';
```

Every time I do this, I get the error:

```
ERROR 1432 (HY000): Can't create federated table. The data source connection string 'mysql://user:password@host.name:3306/' is not in the correct format
```

I've looked at the docs, and I believe that I'm following the docs in this.  What is the proper syntax for this connection string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't following the docs after all. I neglected to add the remote database and table into the connection string. The proper connection string would have been:

```
mysql://user:password@host.name:3306/remote_db/table
```

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure your /etc/my.cnf has

```
[mysqld]
federated
```

Then restart the mysql service. It may not be enabled by default.